# Regex to match 1 2 3 4,5,6

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have a file with lines in the following format

1 2 3 4,5,6

First three delimited by space and the last three delimited by commas.  As an example i've given 1-6 but the values can be alphanumeric value.  Can someone help me with a regular expression to match the entire line to extract the 6 values?

In Java i can use this regex - line.split("[ ,]") and it works, but I am using Hadoop Pig and I need to pass the regex to a method called PigStorage(), which expects the regex to match the entire string.

Here is the doc from Pig-

"Pig does support regular expression matching via the matches keyword. It uses java.util.regex matches which means your pattern has to match the entire string (e.g. if your string is "hi fred" and you want to find "fred" you have to give a pattern of ".*fred" not "fred")."

So I want a regex to match the entire line, and extract the 6 values.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+),(\w+),(\w+)
```

maybe?

Comment: that worked great!  thanks.  what if it is not restricted to just 6, what if the line can contain any number of values like "1 2 3 4 5 6 8,9" or  "10,11,12 13 14 15"...basically the delimiter is either a space or a comma

Comment: If you don't need to capture the individual parts, then you can use `\w+([ ,]\w+)*` which will capture any number of things separated by either a space or a comma.

Comment: Then you need to construct a regex specifically for the number of parts you need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need use capture group here:

```
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\s(\\d)\\s(\\d)\\s(\\d),(\\d),(\\d)");
    Matcher m=p.matcher("1 2 3 4,5,6");
    int cnt=m.groupCount();
    for(int i=1;i<=cnt;++i)
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
```

Comment: this works great, but the problem is the string could be alpha numeric.

Comment: @hese change the *\\d* to *\p{Alnum}* or *[a-zA-Z0-9]*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
([^ ]+){4}([^,]+){2}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\S+ \S+ \S+ \S+,\S+,\S+
```